# how to display data in a gridview using xmldatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

my Code is :

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" 
                                CellSpacing="0" DataMember="TITLE" GridLines="None">
                                <MasterTableView DataMember="TITLE" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
                                    <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF" />
                                    <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
                                        <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
                                    </RowIndicatorColumn>
                                    <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
                                        <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
                                    </ExpandCollapseColumn>
                                    <EditFormSettings>
                                        <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
                                        </EditColumn>
                                    </EditFormSettings>
                                </MasterTableView>
                                <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
                                </FilterMenu>
                                <HeaderContextMenu CssClass="GridContextMenu GridContextMenu_Default">
                                </HeaderContextMenu>
                            </telerik:RadGrid>
                            <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/Bin/xml.xml" EnableCaching="false">
                            </asp:XmlDataSource>
```

When i Debug it, it says "**Cannot find any bindable properties in an item from the datasource** .. What do i do? help please :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me doing that using object data source and we can give the object ds an xml source but for your case  here are some useful links :
http://forums.asp.net/t/1409700.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/bmains/archive/2006/06/25/87.aspx

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/XMLDataSource-Control.aspx

http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3553881/Binding-to-XML-Data-in-ASPNET-20.htm

and here is the best one :

http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/12/22/aspnet-how-to-use-an-xmldatasource-with-a-gridview/
mark as answered if it helps :)

Comment: WHAT IF I DONT WANT TO WRITE A CODEBEHIND IN A <default>.cs FILE AND JUST BIND MY GRID WITH OUT writing it?

Comment: here is another link without any code behind
http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092706-1.aspx